# How to increase the PHP limits in Google Cloud Platform for web

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using wordpress for web design and was asked to contact the host to update to the config below:

```
max_execution_time 360
memory_limit 128M
post_max_size 32M
upload_max_filesize 32M
```

Would you please advise how could I do it in Google Cloud Platform? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does [How To Edit php.ini File IN Google Cloud](https://nahidmahamud.com/how-to-edit-php-ini-file-in-google-cloud/) by Nahid Mahamud help you?

In short:

> 1. Go to your project in google cloud platform
> 2. Go to Computer Engine-> VM instances -> project name
> 3. Click On SSH.
> 4. It will open this [console] window.
> 5. `sudo find / -name "php.ini"` will list the files.

Edit the php.ini file in use with your application & add the settings you need.

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress deployed via official Google Click to Deploy image, you can follow these steps:-

1. SSH into your VM instance
2. Type in the command `sudo find / -name "php.ini"`
3. You will receive a list of files depending on your php version:

```
/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini
/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/8.1/cgi/php.ini
```

4. Edit the fpm/php.ini file using: `sudo nano /etc/php/<php version>/fpm/php.ini` and update the values.
5. Save the file and restart php and apache.

Note: If it doesn't work, try editing the values in `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini` as well.